# How to show partial results from query, then button to show next set

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I built an image gallery. Currently, I loop through all the selected criteria and then populate all images associated with that category. Everything works fine. However, once more images are uploaded, there will be entirely too many images.

So, with this in mind, I was wanting JS to show them 15 image increments. With 15 images shown, if there are more than 15, then there would be a button under it that says "Show More". When that button is clicked then the next 15 show (or if there aren't 15 more images, then whatever is left shows). I guess a form of incremental pagination, without there being additional pages.

How can I do this?

PHP:

```
$category = $_POST['category'];
$projects_sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM project_gallery
        WHERE category = '".$category."'
        ORDER BY date_added DESC
    ";

    if ($projects_stmt = $con->prepare($projects_sql)) {
        $projects_stmt->execute();
        $project_rows = $projects_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $proj_arr = array();
        foreach ($project_rows as $project_row) {
            $project_img = $project_row['p_img'];
            $project_img = substr($project_img, 2);
            $project_alt = $project_row['p_alt'];
            $project_display_img = '<img src="/php'.$project_img.'" alt="'. $project_alt .'" class="projectDisplayImg">';
            $project_title = $project_row['p_name'];
            $html = '';
            $html .= '<div class="projectCont" data-current="'.$category.'">';
            $html .= $project_display_img;
            $html .= '<div class="overlay"><div class="overlayInner"><img src="/Projects/expand.png" alt="Expand MB Kit Project" class="total-center" id="overlayImg"></div></div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $data = array('id' => $project_row['id'], 'date' => $project_row['date_added'], 'html' => $html);
            $proj_arr[] = $data;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($proj_arr);
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/php/projectLoad.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'category': category
        },
        success: function (data) {
          //console.log(data);
            if (data == null) {
                alert("Unable to retrieve projects!");
                alert(data);
            } else {
                var displayProjects = JSON.parse(data);
                $wrapper.empty();
                $(displayProjects).each(function() {
                    $wrapper.append(this.html);
                    //console.log(this.html);
                });
                $wrapper.append(startBuilding);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
            alert('There are currently no project images for this selection');
        }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="projectGallery"></div>
```

Query Update:

```
try {
    $con = getConfig('pdo');
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    if ($projects_stmt = $con->prepare(SELECT * FROM project_gallery WHERE category = :category ORDER BY date_added DESC)) {
        $projects_stmt -> bindParam(':category', $category);
        $projects_stmt->execute();
        $project_rows = $projects_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $proj_arr = array();
```

Comment: ___Big Note___ There is not much point in preparing a query that has no bindable parameter

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) **PROPERLY** in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: I have the parameter. I didn't include all of my PHP. Just enough to show what I am doing.

Comment: The concept you will need to do some research on is called PAGINATION. There are lots of tutorials out there

Comment: `WHERE category = '".$category."'` Is text concatenated into a query. That is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) **PROPERLY**  in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: @RiggsFolly Are you saying to do something like this? `$stmt = $dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO user (firstname, surname) VALUES (:f-name, :s-name)");
$stmt -> bindParam(':f-name', 'John');`

Comment: Yes'ish except that is not the query that you showed us

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just updated my question at the bottom with my interpretation of what you are saying to do. Is that accurate? Do I not call my query in the prepare with a variable? I never knew that was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There is concept called offset in querying document(rows). You can initially load some documents for an instance let say 30 (using limit or top clause). Store that result in an an array and display it. On click to next button add offset to last offset that will become 30 (0+30) so first 30 rows will be neglected. on third time click on button. Add 30 to offset (0+30+30) so first 60 rows will be neglected.

Here is the sample query.

```
SELECT
    product_name,
    list_price
FROM
    production.products
ORDER BY
    list_price,
    product_name 
OFFSET 10 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```